# Customize Date Picker: How to change width & height of datepicker in iphone?

Tags: iphone

Is there any way to customize the datepicker used in iphone?

I want to change height & width of it.
Can we change the background color, font color of it?

Please help if anybody has done before.

Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The size cannot be changed.  There are other questions concerning this and several ways to fake it, moving it partially offscreen or putting other views in front partially obscuring portions or adding background images to make it look larger.  The best approach is to use it as-is or write a custom picker.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can create your own picker ;)

I created this component that allows you to do this really easily: http://dev.doukasd.com/2011/04/infinite-scrolling-dial-control-for-ios/